# Update Winforms controls from Timers

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

I am trying to understand Forms.Timers better.
As I understand, a timer is executed on a thread from the thread pool, in this case you should not update a control on the form from the timer (because this is not the thread that created this control).

But, in the examples provided by microsoft ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/run-procedures-at-set-intervals-with-wf-timer-component ) thay are updating a control from a timer.

So, my question is, is there any problem updating a control (like a label) from a timer (without a control.Invoke call)?

If not, why not? (because this is a thread from the thread pool and not the thread that created the control)

Comment: Attention! [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netcore-3.1) != [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netcore-3.1) != [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netcore-3.1) ...

Comment: There are many `Timer` classes built-in the .NET platform, in different namespaces. Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer#remarks) (scroll down to the green **Tip** section). What type is the timer you are referring to?

Comment: You can definitely update a form control with a Forms.Timer. Please try it and see, and come back if you get stuck on something specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The  [Windows.Forms.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netcore-3.1) is **optimized** to be used with the UI.

From the above link. emphasis mine:

> A Timer is used to raise an event at user-defined intervals. **This Windows timer is designed for a single-threaded environment where UI threads are used to perform processing. It requires that the user code have a UI message pump available and always operate from the same thread**, or marshal the call onto another thread.

The [System.Timers.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject?view=netcore-3.1) has a SynchronizingObject which can be set to the Form Object if you are wanting to use that one.

From Above link:

> When SynchronizingObject is null, the method that handles the Elapsed event is called on a thread from the system-thread pool. For more information on system-thread pools, see ThreadPool.
>   When the Elapsed event is handled by a visual Windows Forms component, such as a button, accessing the component through the system-thread pool might result in an exception or just might not work. **Avoid this effect by setting SynchronizingObject to a Windows Forms component, which causes the method that handles the Elapsed event to be called on the same thread that the component was created on.**